# Amazon GetFeedSubmissionList

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

This is more a 'how are you dealing with this':

1. SubmitFeed (*POST_PRODUCT_DATA*) - Status *SUBMITTED*
2. While Status != "*DONE*" request GetFeedSubmissionList(FeedSubmissionId)
3. When *DONE*
4. request GetFeedSubmissionResult(FeedSubmissionId) to check for errors, if none Update our DB stating it has been successful.

This can take up to 20 minutes per request (if not more). Has anyone found a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that wants to know:

> Amazon: Due to the asynchronous nature of our Feeds API, this is the correct workflow. Thankfully all those steps can be automated.